# Selectively showing latin numbers whithin a xepersian document paragragh

Tags: bidi, xepersian

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xepersian} 
\settextfont{FreeFarsi}% http://sourceforge.net/projects/fpf/
\begin{document}
این یک متن فارسی  است. \LR{Ch4} 
ادامه متن فارسی...
\end{document}
```

It prints `\LR{Ch4}` as Ch۴, whereas I want it to be printed as Ch4. But I do not want this to effect other numbers in the text. How can I do this?

I could use `\begin{latin}...\end{latin}` or `\latin ... \persian`, but they add new lines before and after the contained text.

Comment: What you need is `\lr{Ch4}` instead of `\LR{Ch4}` .

Comment: Thanks. Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `\LR{text}` from **bidi** package to write short "left to right" text inside RTL document "right to left" without any treatment or change to the text.

In **Xepersian** package numbers are defined  like this ۱ ۲ ۳ ۴  even though written  1 2 3 4, So to avoid this you can simply put them  within the `\lr` command, and your code become

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xepersian} 
\settextfont{FreeFarsi}% http://sourceforge.net/projects/fpf/
\begin{document}
این یک متن فارسی  است. \lr{Ch4} 
ادامه متن فارسی...
\end{document}
```

You can take a look to the **Xepersian**  manual page 41.