# Problem with english number in xepersian package

Tags: right-to-left, xepersian

I'm writing a document using xepersian package to write Kurdish in Latex.Every thing work perfect but the only problem is when I want number in every place in my latex file to be like ( 123456789). but whatever I do it will change it to (١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩).
By the way I have been used \DefaultMathsDigits command and its work only inside math but, I want to also work inside my kurdish text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Unikurd Nali}
\setlatintextfont[Scale]{Courier}
\setdigitfont{Arial}
\DefaultMathsDigits
\begin{document}

گه‌ر ئه‌مه‌ به‌كوردی بنووسم 123445 ئه‌وا ده‌یگۆرێت ب١٢٣٤٥.
\end{document}
```

Note:- It look like there is a command (\lr ) that is solve this problem, but I think this is not practical, since in Kurdish we are using English number but arabic-like alphabet. I wonder if there should be better solution to this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!, take a look to this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249859/selectively-showing-latin-numbers-whithin-a-xepersian-document-paragragh/250655#250655).

Comment: @salimbou thanks, But I think this is not practical, imagine I have to write an article and contains 100 number, so I have to use this command 100 time. but of course if there is no other solution I have to use it. So I was interested if there is any more efficient way to do this. but thanks again this is very useful.

Comment: So use `polyglossia` rather then `xepersian` to define format of number.

Comment: thanks, but not sure if polyglossia is work perfectly as xepersian with Kurdish alphabet.

Comment: It work perfectly with arabic, farsi, urdu,... we can define the format for numbering with `numerals=maghrib` which give 1, 2, 3,... or  `numerals=machriq` which give ٣، ٢، ١

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code can be written with `polyglossia`, i have not `Unikurd Nali` font so i use `Amiri` font available  both in `miktex` and `texlive`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
\begin{document}

\section{السلام عليكم}

گه‌ر ئه‌مه‌ به‌كوردی بنووسم 123445 ئه‌وا ده‌یگۆرێت ب١٢٣٤٥.

\end{document}
```

[image]