# Change format of section numbering in Lyx

Tags: sectioning, numbering, lyx, arabic, right-to-left

I am using Lyx to write a document in Arabic Language. My problem in numbering of the sections and subsections.

In arabic, text direction is from right to left. So when I created sections and subsections, say for example in the following shot:

[image]

So Section 2 is ok, but for subsection it should be ".1.2" (so that we read it from right to left correctly) but as you see in the shot it is ".2.1".

So please tell me there is a way to fix this. (please note that I depend on these section and subsections numbering to create Table Of Content automatically).

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in Advance

Please see the following sample code for debugging

```
      % Preview source code

%% LyX 2.1.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
\setmonofont{Arial}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase \rightmark}
%\fancyfoot[L]{\scriptsize Design and Verification of MP3 Decoding Stage}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
%\fancyfoot[R]{\scriptsize Mohammed Ibrahim}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\begin{document}

\section{المقدمات العامة }


\subsection{تعريفه: }

لغةً هو التحسين. اصطلاحاً هو علم يبحث في الكلمات


\subsection{موضوعه: }

الكلمات 


\subsection{نسبته: }

أحد العلوم


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Yes i think its clear, but you can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Comment: Does [Problem with english number in xepersian package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263339/124842) do the job? I tried with xelatex.

Comment: Is the output in the PDF correct?

Comment: OK. I know next to nothing  about Arabic and RTL, but I think more information would be needed. In the source pane, select *Complete document* instead of *Body only*, or whatever is selected, and copy-paste that instead. After pasting the code into your question, select it and click the button marked `{}`, which will highlight it properly as code.

Comment: @TorbjørnT, I hope the sample code is clear now

Comment: Yes, and I do see the problem (That is, I get e.g. ٢ instead of 2, but the direction is LTR instead of RTL.) I have no idea where the problem lies though, hopefully someone else does.

Comment: I would say the first thing to try is a recent version of LyX. LyX 2.3.0 will have a lot of fixes, and if I remember correctly we had some recent fixes that were specific to Arabic. I think in the future 2.4.0 release we might even have an Arabic translation of our help files.

Comment: I think this is a `polyglossia` problem. `xepersian` gives the output you want. LyX probably just treats the section numbers using the standard unicode bidi algorithm and outputs them LTR. But it doesn't matter what they look like in LyX, it's the `xelatex` output that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling this is not really the right way to do this. But here at least is a work around. It won't affect your display in LyX, but should output correctly.

Add this to your preamble:

```
% force numbered labels to be set RTL
\makeatletter
\def\SepMark#1{\gdef\@SepMark{\hboxR{#1}}}%
\makeatother
\SepMark{.}
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Script=Arabic]
% force numbered labels to be set RTL
\makeatletter
\def\SepMark#1{\gdef\@SepMark{\hboxR{#1}}}%
\makeatother
\SepMark{.}
\begin{document}
\section{المقدمات العامة}
\subsection{تعريفه:}
لغةً هو التحسين. اصطلاحاً هو علم يبحث في الكلمات
\subsection{موضوعه:}
الكلمات 
\subsection{نسبته:}
أحد العلوم
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Concerning LyX

In LyX, you probably need a bit more. In Document --> Settings --> LaTeX Preamble, add

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\SepMark#1{\gdef\@SepMark{\hboxR{#1}}}%
  \SepMark{.}%
}
```

The `\AtBeginDocument` is needed because by default LyX will add `polyglossia` *after* the code one adds in the preamble. And so I guess the `SepMark` will be modified back to it's default. (It's not necessary to add `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` because LyX inserts those.)